# Как установить условие к добавлению на панель

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

Есть привязка текстбоксов

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _bs.Count; i++)
        {
            //привязка текстбоксов
            var textBox  = _panelMulti.Controls
                .OfType<TextBox>().First(t => t.Name.EndsWith((i + 1).ToString()));
            textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bs[i],
         nameof(Answer.Value), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);


            //привязка чекбоксов
            var checkbox = _panelMulti.Controls
                .OfType<CheckBox>().First(t => t.Name.EndsWith((i + 1).ToString()));
            checkbox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _bs[i], nameof(Answer.IsCorrect));

        }
```

И нужно текстбоксы проверить на наличие содержимого, если же они пустые то не добавлять, я пытался сделать `textbox.text == String.Empty`, но это не то.
А с checkbox-ами проще их нужно доб-ть, столько же сколько и textbox

Загрузка самих текстбохов

```
private void LoadAnswers()
    {
        var currentQuestion = _bsQuestions.Current as Question;
        var bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = currentQuestion.Answers;

        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        if (currentQuestion.Type == QuestionType.SingleSelect )
        {
            uc = new UserControlSingle(bs);
            label4.Text = $"select 1 of { bs.Count} the answers";
        }
        else
        {
            uc = new UserControlMulti(bs);
            label4.Text = $"select several of { bs.Count} the answers";


        }
        _panel.Controls.Clear();
        _panel.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

там только привязка происходит а вот здесь мы добавляем, вот как это сделать не пойму

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример проверки на пустоту

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.text)) {
    // что-то сделать если не пустой
}

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.text)) {
    // что-то сделать если пустой
}
```

Comment: он не показывает данные, должен не добавлять, или же лучше сделать что бы при этом условии удалять

Comment: @SmurW Ну уберите отрицание и тогда будет добавление в непустой.

Comment: выдите вот эту строчку? `textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bs[i],
         nameof(Answer.Value), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);` так вот здесь он проходит по массиву и добавляет объекты с типом <TextBox> а мне нужно что бы он удалял, а с таким условием он мне просто не показывает данные может сделать типо того textBox.DataBindings.Remove(?) вот только как ?

Comment: Нужно чтобы удалялись textbox с формы? Так вы их не добавляйте. Поставьте проверку на пустоту и не добавляйте.

Comment: я добавил изменения я пытался сделать то что вы мне говорите, но я делаю не правильно

Comment: код просто не мой и я даже не могу понять как обратиться в этом случае к i - textbox-у

Comment: Вот эту строку вставьте в условие `textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bs[i],
         nameof(Answer.Value), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`

Comment: @because извините но я не со всем понимаю о чем вы?

Comment: Привязка данных только для непустого текстбокса.